# No property delete found for type Expense

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am currently doing some fullstack java tutorial with angular. I am using mysql base and table called expenses. I am using hibarnate and JPA.
I have some problems with Rest Api @DeleteMapping :
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Expense!

Here are my classes:

Expense.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="expenses")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String expense;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal amount;

}
```

ExpenseREpository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {

    Expense save(Expense expense);

    Optional<Expense> findById(Long id);

    void delete(Long id);
}
```

ExpenseService.java

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ExpenseService {

    private final ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;

    public List<Expense> findAll() {
        return expenseRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Expense save(Expense expense) {
        return expenseRepository.save(expense);
    }

    public Optional<Expense> findById(Long id) {
        return expenseRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        expenseRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

and there is my controller :

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ExpenseController {

    private final ExpenseService expenseService;

    @GetMapping("/expenses")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Expense>> getList() {
        return new ResponseEntity(expenseService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/expenses")
    public ResponseEntity<Expense> save(@RequestBody Expense expense) {
        return new ResponseEntity(expenseService.save(expense), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/expenses/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Expense> getExpense(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity(expenseService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/expenses/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteExpense(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        expenseService.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity("Expense id: " + id + " is deleted successfully!" , HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

here is my sample of output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.expensetracker.tutorial.repository.ExpenseRepository.delete(java.lang.Long)! No property delete found for type Expense!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1879) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:53) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:35) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.expensetracker.tutorial.ExpensetrackerApplication.main(ExpensetrackerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.expensetracker.tutorial.repository.ExpenseRepository.delete(java.lang.Long)! No property delete found for type Expense!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:303) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:271) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:58) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Expense!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 54 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Have tried to set some query for delete method in repository like this :

```
   @Modifying
    @Query("From expenses Where id like %:id%")
    void delete(@Param("id")Long id);
```

but i am getting output like my table is not mapped.
So my question is : Shall i  create interface for mapping id parameters? I don't really know how to resolve that. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing all information that you need:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.expensetracker.tutorial.repository.ExpenseRepository.delete(java.lang.Long)! No property delete found for type Expense!

Update this:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {
    ....
    void deleteById(Long id);
   ...
}
```